# WordPress plugin to add image grids to post content

Tags: wordpress

My client wants to be able to layout photos in their post content in a responsive grid format.

For my last project, I actually built a custom function to do this for me, but I'm curious if there is a better method out there that's already been hashed out. Because the method I built isn't very user friendly, and it only allows for certain image aspect ratios.

I also have one client that's using this plugin: [Column Shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/column-shortcodes/), but I don't think it's as robust as I'd like it.

Basically let's say the client wants to be able to create a layout similar to this:

[image: example layout]

Is there a plugin that can help them manage creating grids within the post content like this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many many plugins that can do this but I think the easiest would be any page builder or layout editor. The one that I use is called Page Builder by SiteOrigin. It's free and extremely easy to use. You will be able to add images in the layout that you want including the examples given in the question.

Some nice features are,

- Works with any theme
- No coding required
- Live editing
- History Browser
- Row and widget styles
- In active development

## [Page Builder by SiteOrigin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/) Free

> Page Builder by SiteOrigin is the most popular page creation plugin for WordPress. It makes it easy to create responsive column based content, using the widgets you know and love. Your content will accurately adapt to all mobile devices, ensuring your site is mobile-ready.
>
> [image]

Comment: Interesting. I will definitely give this a try to see if it works in my situation. I will report back.